# How to achieve click an area outside the TextField to make the TextField lose focus?

Tags: qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextField {
        id:textField
        width: 130
        height: 50
    }

    Button {
        anchors.right: parent.right
        text: "lose Focus"
    }
}
```

why textField don't lose Focus when Button Click?
How to achieve click an area outside the TextField to make the TextField lose focus?

Comment: Suggestion to add an API for this to Qt: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72901

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way using your existing code is to [force active focus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method) on another item when the button is clicked:

```
Button {
    anchors.right: parent.right
    text: "lose Focus"
    onClicked: forceActiveFocus()
}
```

To make the `TextField` lose focus when clicking the area outside of it, you can do something similar with `MouseArea`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: forceActiveFocus()
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField
        width: 130
        height: 50
    }
}
```

This item needs to be below (i.e have a lower Z value than) other items in the scene. You can also make it a parent of the other items to achieve this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: forceActiveFocus()

        TextField {
            id: textField
            width: 130
            height: 50
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using Qt Quick Controls 2, you can use the [`focusPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#focusPolicy-prop) property on e.g. `Pane`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Pane {
        anchors.fill: parent
        focusPolicy: Qt.ClickFocus
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField
        width: 130
        height: 50
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,I used the combination of the first and the fifth.But I think this should not be the best solution

Comment: I'm curious what you think a better solution would be?

Comment: If there are many buttons on the UI,doing so would be complicated.If you have a title bar, clicking on the title bar still does not make it lose focus.But I don't know what better way to solve it.

Comment: Well you only need one e.g. Pane item with `focusPolicy` set to handle this. I don't see how this is complicated: you do it once in one place and it's done. :) The forceActiveFocus() is only necessary if you for some reason don't want to use that approach.

Comment: @Mitch Hey thanks for the answer. I tried to use this but seems like container such as ScrollView block the click event. In your example it would be that the TextField is in ScrollView which is filling the whole page. The Pane or MouseArea is then unreachable. Do you have any tip how to deal with it?

Comment: Try using a `TapHandler` in the `ScrollView`: `TapHandler { onTapped: textField.focus = false }`. If that doesn't work, I'd recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @Mitch Maan thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! Didn't know that such handler existed! Thanks again, works like a charm!