# QML: Accept TextField onClicked outside

Tags: qt, qml, controls, focus, textfield

Imagine the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextField {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onEditingFinished: console.log("input is: " + text)
    }
}
```

How do I achive that the input of the TextField is accepted (onEditingFinished emitted), on clicking anywhere outside of the TextField (not pressing enter, tab,.. just a mouse click)?

I might set a MouseArea around it with `onClicked: forceActiveFocus()` to force onEditingFinished, but how do I achive this within a large application with many layers/views? This does not seem to be the right solution.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#editingFinished-signal): "This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed *or the text field loses focus.*" Doesn't it already do what you want?

Comment: Related: [SO-55101332](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55101332/16586783)

Comment: you can monitor `onActiveFocus: if (!activeFocus) doSomething()`

Answer (score 0):

You can take this approach:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (root.activeFocusItem != null) {
                root.activeFocusItem.focus = false;
            }
        }
    }

    TextField {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onEditingFinished: console.log("input is: " + text)
    }
}
```

This places a single MouseArea filling your Window as a backstop to anything that might appear above it. Either a mouse click will be accepted by a control sitting above the mouse area or will pass through to it and clear focus on anything that might have it.