# How to loose focus when i click outside TextInput in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have three elements inside `Column` i.e. `Button`, `Rectangle` and `ListView`. `TextInput` is the child of `Rectangle`. When select/click on any item in `ListView`, the cursor is still visible in `TextInput`. I want the cursor to be available ONLY when i'm editing the `TextInput` and not otherwise.

For simplicity sake, i have removed unnecessary code.

```
Column {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Button {
        id: backButton
        onClicked: { . . . }       
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: myRect

        TextInput  {
            id: inputText
            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }
            cursorVisible: false
            onAccepted: { // do something}
        }
    }

    ListView {
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve click an area outside the TextField to make the TextField lose focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101332/how-to-achieve-click-an-area-outside-the-textfield-to-make-the-textfield-lose-fo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put a MouseArea somewhere to catch the outside mouse clicks and move the focus away from the TextInput. Something like this should work:

```
Column {
    Button {
    }

    Rectangle {
        TextInput  {
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: listView.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }
}
```